# Targeting child of parent - jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parent, children

I've got a series of posts in wordpress, each will have hidden section which displays on click of a link.
Having trouble targeting the child of that particular post, as a normal div reference makes all the hidden section appear at once..

```
<div class="individual">
    <div class="m-all t-1of4 d-1of4">
        <a class="headshot" href="" style="color: #000 !important">
            <h3>Test</h3>    
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="desciption-show" style="display: none; background: #ffffff;">
        <div class="m-all t-all d-all cf">
            <h3>Testasdf</h3>
            <h4>Testasdfasdfasdf</h4>
            <p>Testdghjfghjfghj</p>
            <p><em>fghjrtysdfgdfgh</em></p>
            <a class="close" href="">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.headshot").click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".individual").children('.description-show').show('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Wordpress, jQuery is generally in no-conflict mode, so you'll need a different DOM ready handler.

An empty `href` attribute will reload the page when the anchor is clicked, so you probably want to prevent that.

`closest` seems like a better choice for targeting the parent elements, as it stops when the element is found, which `parents` doesn't.

The classname has a typo, it's should be `description-show`, not `desciption-show`

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".headshot").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).closest(".individual").children('.description-show').show('fast');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/21479fa2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `closest()` function to target parent and then find child inside parent element, try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.headshot").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".individual").children('.desciption-show').show('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
<div class="desciption-show" style="display: none; background: #ffffff;">
```

because it's written wrong,

```
$('.description-show')
```

change the div class from **desciption-show** to **description-show**.

plus, I would find my element this way

```
$(".headshot").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".individual").find('.description-show').show();
});
```

This is  [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwLtv30d/2/).

Hope this helps